# What will happen if the same question is asked on Stack Overflow and Super User?

Tags: support, stack-overflow, superuser, migration

For example, a user asked this question on Stack Overflow:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1717653/re-enable-animated-gif-display-in-firefox

...and the same question already exists on Super User:

[Re-enable animated GIF display in Firefox?](https://superuser.com/questions/69165/re-enable-animated-gif-display-in-firefox/69166)

...so, what will happen to the Stack Overflow question? Can it not be migrated to Super User because it's already available there?

Comment: Edit the question again. I meant to up-vote the question because Shog9 fixed the spelling. I undid my down-vote, then tried to up-vote only to get the error message that my vote was too old to be changed. I didn't realize that I should have just clicked the up vote.

Comment: Edited again. Change your vote if you so desire...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Normally the Stack Overflow question would get migrated to Super User where it would get closed as an exact duplicate.

This is as expected and by design.

However, in this case the Stack Overflow question has been deleted.

Answer (score 3):

As for the cause of this problem: I think many questions are re-posted on Super User *after* people commented on the original question with things like *"Belongs on superuser.com"*. I know typing a bit more (like *"but don't ask the same question there; the above will be moved if needed"*) is cumbersome, but it's surely appreciated!